# How to use a Hyperlink function in apex class?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a requirement to get the Contacts of an object to the Description of an Account. For that i Created a VF page Section in Account Object and Linked one VF Page which is having a button in it.

Whenever the user clicks the button, the Page will refresh and will get the Contacts links in the Description Field

Below is my **VF page Code**

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" Extensions="LookupMainController" showChat="false" sidebar="false" showHeader="false">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:commandButton value="Get Contacts" action="{!callContact}"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Below is my **Apex Class (Controller) Code**

```
public with sharing class LookupMainController 
{
    public List<Id> cid;
    public String accountName {get; set;}
    public Id accountId {get; set;}
    public List<Contact> contacts {get;set;}

    public LookupMainController(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        accountId = controller.getId();
    }
    public PageReference callContact(){
        //Getting all the Contacts referred to an Account
        if(accountId != null){
            contacts = [select id,Name,FirstName,AccountId,LastName from Contact where AccountId =: accountId ORDER BY CreatedDate];
        }
        //Getting the Description field of Account to null
        List<Account> AccList = [select Id,Name,Description from Account where Id =: accountId];
        Map<Id,Account> UpdateAcc = new Map<Id,Account>();
        for(Account acc : AccList){
            acc.Description = '';
            updateAcc.put(acc.Id,acc);
        }
        if(UpdateAcc.size()>0)
        update UpdateAcc.values();
        //Putting the Contacts as Hyperlinks in Description Field
        for(Account acc : AccList){
            for(Contact c : contacts){
                acc.Description += System.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/'+c.Id+' ';
                UpdateAcc.put(acc.Id,acc);
            }
        }
        if(UpdateAcc.size()>0)
        Update UpdateAcc.values();
        //Putting the Pagereference just to reload the same Account Page
        Id acId;
        for(Account ac : AccList){
            acId = ac.Id;
        }
        PageReference pg = new PageReference('/'+acId);
        return pg;
    }
}
```

Now in the Output, i am getting the Description field as the Group of Links. But instead of Links i want to get both the Name and Link of a particular contact within a Description Field.

See the screenshot for Output i am getting

[image]

Is there any way to get the Contact Name and Link respectively?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are preparing link it self since description is long text area field

Just iterate over contacts and add Name in description

try like this.

```
//Putting the Contacts as Hyperlinks in Description Field
for(Account acc : AccList){
    for(Contact c : contacts){
        acc.Description += c.Name +'  '+;
        UpdateAcc.put(acc.Id,acc);
    }
}
```

---

### Updates

Create a rich text area and create link with Contact Name

For example your rich text area field name is `CustomField__c`

```
for(Account acc : AccList){
    for(Contact c : contacts){
        acc.CustomField__c += '<a href=' +System.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/'+c.Id+' >'+ c.Name+'</a> <br/>';
        UpdateAcc.put(acc.Id,acc);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but whenever i clicked the name, it should take me to the respected contact. With your answer, i will get only the name in the Description field but not the Link.

Comment: @Subhash for that you need rich text area field. You can't do it with long text area type field.. Create a rich text area field and try above code what you have written then It will work as you expected.

Comment: can you plz send me the code or reference or link using with that rich text area field?

Comment: @Subhash give me a min I will add in my ans..

Comment: @Subhash check my updated ans..

Comment: @Subhash nice...