# Add a hyperlink in the body of the notes

Tags: apex, hyperlink

I am trying to add a hyperlink to an Opportunity in the body of a note record. Something like this

```
note n = new note();
n.ParentId = {OpptyId};
n.title = 'Note from code';
n.body ='<a href=' +System.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/'+PrimaryId.get(op.Id)+' >'+'Closed Cleanup'+'</a> <br/>';
Insert n;
```

However, when note is created I see body-

```
<a href=https://ap8.salesforce.com/0060o00001BFCSZ>Closed Cleanup </a> <br/>
```

But I want body of note to have Closed Cleanup as clickable and should be redirecting on clicking to - https://ap8.salesforce.com/0060o00001BFCSZ

I took the reference from - [How to use a Hyperlink function in apex class?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/114116/how-to-use-a-hyperlink-function-in-apex-class) which says Rich Text Area field can contain the hyperlink. If that's true , how do I add a hyperlink to a note record?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the old `Note` object, which supports only plaintext in the body.  See [Note documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_note.htm).

If you want to use rich text in a note, you need to [enable the new Notes functionality](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=notes_setup_enable.htm&type=5) and then use the new `ContentNote` object.  See [ContentNote documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentnote.htm)

Comment: How do I add a hyperlink in the ContentNote? It will be great if you can share an example or so?